# ¿Cómo actualizo un campo una pagina de ajustes personalizada en el plugin 'pods' de wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, pods

Esta es la forma de recoger un campo de una página de ajustes personalizados.

Inicializo mi variable de $settings:

```
$settingspage = pods('nombredeminamedeajustes');
```

Recojo el valor de mi campo:

```
$nombredemicampo = $settings->field('nombredemicampo');
```

Comment: @Shaz me cuesta mucho no decir value o field y eso que soy Español :S jaja, lo digo por la edición.

Comment: Lo que más me preocupó fue el verbo "updatear", creo que dista bastante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya me he acordado, de esta forma puedo guardar el valor que quiera en mi campo custom:

```
$nombredemicampo = $settings->save('nombredemicampo', 'elvalorqueyoquiera');
```